# Where can I find my extensions for php in centos when using yum install memcache

Tags: php

Just as the title says. I need my memcache.so to put it in the php.ini, but I cannot find it after installing it with package manager yum install memcached.

Anyone please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think memcached RPM includes php extension, or centos doesn't maintain the extension. You may need to install it manually:

```
cd /usr/src
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/memcache-2.2.6.tgz
tar zxvf memcache-2.2.6.tgz
cd memcache-2.2.6
phpize
./configure
make
make install
```

If you are using XAMPP(Linux), you need to install xampp-linux-devel and use `phpize` in `/opt/lampp/bin/`. If you haven't installed devel files of Xampp yet, first you need to isntall XAMPP-devel package(expecting your XMAPP version is 1.7.7):

```
wget http://www.apachefriends.org/download.php?xampp-linux-devel-1.7.7.tar.gz
mv download.php\?xampp-linux-devel-1.7.7.tar.gz xampp-linux-devel-1.7.7.tar.gz
tar xvfz xampp-linux-devel-1.7.7.tar.gz -C /opt
```

Then try the same installation but use `/opt/lampp/bin/phpize` instead of `phpize`

```
cd /usr/src
wget http://pecl.php.net/get/memcache-2.2.6.tgz
tar zxvf memcache-2.2.6.tgz
cd memcache-2.2.6
/opt/lampp/bin/phpize
./configure --with-php-config=/opt/lampp/bin/php-config
make
make install
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It worked to compile it but I'm now getting this error: 
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so' - /opt/lampp/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/memcache.so: wrong ELF class: ELFCLASS64 in Unknown on line 0

Comment: I guess you are using xampp for linux? I editted my answer adding some tips for xampp environment. could you try and see if that works?

Comment: Okey I'll give it a try when I'm home this evening. Thanks in advance

Comment: Now the xampp devel packages are available at `BETAS` directory:
https://sourceforge.net/projects/xampp/files/BETAS/